# System.Windows.Forms.TextBox align text center left

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a windows TextBox. Is there an easy way to set the text alignment to Middle left. The TextBox is multiline.

Comment: You cant align text vertical if thats what you want to do.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/ru-RU/712d4df4-64e4-4748-8bff-6b9ed0db46fb/textbox-text-vertical-alignment?forum=winforms

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: Guess this is wrong, he want to align it to the left and vertical align it to the middle I suppose

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like "Middle Left" alignment for `TextBox`. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign.aspx), only

```
HorizontalAlignment.Center
HorizontalAlignment.Left 
HorizontalAlignment.Right
```

are valid.

Answer (score 0):

select your text box in windows form and go property window where you can find the text align property to set text according to your requirement....

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment can't be adjusted: there's no such property.

**The text is always vertically in the middle of the line. The line height is relative to the used font size.**

You can only set the horizontal alignment:

```
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

Answer (score 0):

textBox1.TextAlign = "Center";
This works for me as well